# python3 subprocess in Oracle Linux (wget -o)

Tags: python-3.x, path, subprocess

I see there are several posts on python subprocess invoking bash shell commands. But I can't find an answer to my problem unless someone has a link that I'm missing.

So here is a start of my code.

```
import os;
import subprocess;
    subprocess.call("wget ‐O /home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm");
```

When I do

```
wget ‐O /home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

straight up in terminal, it works.

But my IDE gives me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wget'`

Again, I'm new to invoking os/subprocess module within python and I would appreciate any insight on how to use these modules effectively.

{UPDATE: with miindlek's answer, I get these errors. 1st - `subprocess.call(["wget", "‐O", "/home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm", "https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm"])`}

```
--2015-06-07 17:14:37--  http://%E2%80%90o/
Resolving ‐o... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address “‐o”
/home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm: Scheme missing.
--2015-06-07 17:14:52--  https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

{with 2nd bash method `subprocess.call("wget ‐O /home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm", shell=True)`}

```
Resolving yum.puppetlabs.com... 198.58.114.168, 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe69:6bf0
Connecting to yum.puppetlabs.com|198.58.114.168|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10184 (9.9K) [application/x-redhat-package-manager]
Saving to: “puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm.1”

     0K .........                                             100% 1.86M=0.005s

2015-06-07 17:14:53 (1.86 MB/s) - “puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm.1” saved [10184/10184]

FINISHED --2015-06-07 17:14:53--
Downloaded: 1 files, 9.9K in 0.005s (1.86 MB/s)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your command string into a list of arguments:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["wget", "-O", "/home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm", "https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm"])
```

You could also use the shell option as an alternative:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("wget -O /home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm", shell=True)
```

By the way, in python you don't need to add semicolons at the end of a line.

**Update**
The dash in option -O is a utf8 hyphen Charakter, not a dash. See for example:

```
>>> a = "‐"  # utf8 hyphen
>>> b = "-"  # dash
>>> str(a)
'\xe2\x80\x9'
>>> str(b)
'-'
```

You should delete your old dash and relace it by a normal one. I updated the former source code. You can also copy it from there.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Did you forgoet "," between 'rpm' and 'http://'?  I'm getting can't resolve to -o errors. Also, files are being saved in "/home/oracle/IdeaProjects/Puppet/src" and not in Downloads folder. But thanks again!

Comment: Thank you. I'm running this on IntelliJ. Would you know why files are being saved in IdeaProjects instead of my home folder? Would it behave normally if I run the script as a file from home folder?

Comment: Oh, not sure which one I'm using. What do I do in either case? (I'm relatively new to python scripting and linux admin)

Comment: I guess I want absolute. But what am I doing it wrong? to not end up in Downloads but inside IdeaProjects?

Comment: thank you again for your time. What do you mean by replacing old with new characters? hmm, file still not being saved in Downloads but at IdeaProjects.

Comment: Nevermind, I just put the script in Downloads folder with "#!../python" instead of the IDE. It is working. Thanks again for your time and effort in your answer. That was very kind.

Comment: Replaced it and 2015-06-08 11:10:54 (3.20 MB/s) - “/home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm” saved [10184/10184] !!!

Comment: OK. It was actually the dash character which is a utf8 hyphen character, not a dash.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds primarily because your IDE is launching that python subprocess from *not* 'straight up in a terminal'.

This will be a reading suggestion, rather than a direct answer to only this problem.

Check your IDE; read docs about how it launches stuff.

1 - in terminal
type  `$ env`     where you tested    `$ wget`

2 - in IDE
`import os ; print(os.environ)`

3 - read here about shell and Popen
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Begin the learning process from there.

I would even suggest replacing

`subprocess.call("wget -O /home/oracle/Downloads/puppet-repo.rpm https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm", shell=True)`

With a clear declaration of what 'shell' you want to use

`subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'wget' '<stuff>'])`

to mitigate future IDE/shell/env assumption problems.